# PHP Securely include files + handle invalid parameters

Tags: php, security, include

I'm having a little problem. I want to securely include files based on the $_GET Parameter from a subdirectory + handle if the parameter is not valid.

```
 <?php
if(isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] == 'fahrzeuge'){
        include 'includes/cars.php';
    }
  if(isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] == 'impressum'){
        include 'includes/impressum.php';
    }
    if(isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] == 'home'){
            include 'includes/home.php';
        }
      if(isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] == 'anfahrt'){
            include 'includes/anfahrt.php';
        }
        if(isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] == 'about'){
                include 'includes/about.php';
            }

?>
```

This is my Code. Sorry I know it is a noob way of solving this. How can I improve it? Any Suggestions/Help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [ternary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to set a variable that tells the page what to include.

This is very similar to [Ofir Baruch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47308715/5827005)'s answer, except much shorter.

```
$pages = array('about','contact','home');

$p = isset($_GET['p']) && in_array($_GET['p'], $pages)? $_GET['p'] : 'home';
include "includes/{$p}.php";
```

Basically, you have an array of pages that are possible. In the ternary, we check if `$_GET['p']` is set (`isset()`), AND we check if the value it contains is in the array. If it is, we use `$_GET['p']` as `$p`, if it is not, we set `$p` to `home`, this means that `home` will always be the default if `$_GET['p']` is not set, or not a valid page as per the array.

Answer (score 3):

Set an array of legit pages. Check once if `$_GET['p']` is set and if so assign its value (after escaping it) to a variable `$p`.

Then check if the requested page (`$p`) is defined in your pages array, if so - include it.

```
$pages = array('about','contact','home');

$p = 'home'; //Default page
if(isset($_GET['p'])) {
  $p = $_GET['p']; //no need to escape as we compare it to predefined values as @Yoshi suggested
} 

if(in_array($p, $pages)){
  include 'includes/'.$p.'.php';
} else {
   include 'includes/home.php';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I will test it and accept your question if it works. Or in case it doesn't work the way I want. I will let you know or ask you

Comment: Sure, no problem. Update me.

Comment: Is it actually necessary to do `htmlspecialchars()` AND check against an array? If `$p` contains special characters, it just won't load anything because the value wouldn't be in the array. If it's a page name, it has to be a file name, which means that there shouldn't be any special characters anyways except I guess _maybe_ a space

Comment: Hey, it does work + but I also want to handle if a user is trying to modify the parameter. In this case the page includes nothing and looks horrible, thus I want to include the home page. I'm afraid it's something really simple :P

Comment: Don't escape `p`, just use it as the array key, and the value to include the page.

Comment: @floreich Just add `else { include 'includes/home.php'; }` to the end of your `in_array` if statement.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. I highly appreciate that

Comment: Updated the code following your suggestions @GrumpyCrouton & Yoshi

Answer (score 0):

This is the fastes and best way, i am a fan of short codes
and found this from (HACKBUGZ PHP).

You have an array with **array keys** and **array values**.

**EXAMPLE 1**

```
<?php

    $PAGES          = array();
  
    $PAGES = [
       'home'       => 'home.html'
      ,'about'      => 'about.php'
      ,'contact'    => 'somedir/contact.php'
    ];

    @include(substr($PAGES[$_GET['p']] ?? ('home'), 0, 255));

    exit;

?>
```

1. You can have **different query names, filenames, filetypes and directorys**.
2. the **@** catch the include error if file not exists.
3. **substr($PAGES, 0, 255)** cuts the uri to 255 chars(if you dont like that
   just do it without)
4. **($PAGES[$_GET['p']] ?? ('home'))** checks if query (array_key) exists in array if not 'home' will be the default

**EXAMPLE 2(without substr)**

```
<?php

    $PAGES          = array();
  
    $PAGES = [
       'home'       => 'home.html'
      ,'about'      => 'about.php'
      ,'contact'    => 'somedir/contact.php'
    ];

    @include($PAGES[$_GET['p']] ?? ('home'));

    exit;

?>
```